# How to define an empty custom HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I know we can create custom tags directly like this:

```
<material-button>Cancel</material-button>
```

However, I would like to use an **empty tag** without creating a custom element (web component). Is it possible?

```
<icon-star>
```

Comment: No! it is not possible. However please elaborate what exactly you are trying to do here?

Comment: I wanna use my own custom semantic tags. Some of them have something inside, others not, like the example above with the `<icon-star>` it could be just a `background-image` with a start or `content` star symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `<icon-star></icon-star>` only.

You cannot use `<icon-star>` or `<icon-star/>` because it will be interpreted as an opening tag, and all content after will be interpreted as children nodes.

It's due to the way the custom elements are initialized: as unknowned element, so the parser cannot know if they are empty (atomic) or not. Only standard HTML elements can have that property (`<img>`, `<br>`) because they are already known when they are parsed.

```js
customElements.define( 'icon-star', class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = '*'
  }
} )
```

```html
OK: <icon-star></icon-star>
Fail: <icon-star/> Hello
Fail: <icon-star/>
```

So actually you can use the open-only `<icon-star>` syntax for the last element of the page :-o

Comment: And those standard  HTML elements not requiring a closing tag __*can*__ be extended as **Customized Built-In Elements**; But alas Apple refuses to implement that part of the Custom Elements standard.... Still doesn't allow you to create your own tags; notation will be ``<img is=icon-star>``